# rest assured sprint security login

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, rest-assured

I am trying to test my app using rest assured, I am using spring security 
This is sthe code

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://myapp-breakid.rhcloud.com/";
        RestAssured.port = 80;
        Response response  = expect().given().auth().form("admin", "sababa1.",springSecurity().withLoggingEnabled(new LogConfig())).
        when().get("login");
```

but this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2014 20:38:57 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://myapp-breakid.rhcloud.com/index
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=32E5F577A6885826DF17ACEE4B3386AF; Path=/; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges: none
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: to get sessionid and to perform rest request using this sessionid as authenticated user.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go to the login page to login, REST Assured does this automatically. This works:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://myapp-breakid.rhcloud.com";
RestAssured.authentication = form("admin", "sababa1.", springSecurity());

get("/index").prettyPrint();
```

What happens here is that form authentication is automatically performed before each request. If it's important to use the same session in multiple requests you should use a [session filter](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Session_Filter). For example:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://myapp-breakid.rhcloud.com";

SessionFilter sessionFilter = new SessionFilter();

given().
        auth().form("admin", "sababa1.", springSecurity()).
        filter(sessionFilter).
when().
        get("/index");

// Session filter will automatically capture the session id and you can reuse it in subsequent requests.

given().
        filter(sessionFilter).
when().
        get("/another_protected_resource").
then().
        statusCode(200);
```

You can also get the sessionId from the SessionFilter and use it like this:

```
given().
        sessionId(sessionFilter.getSessionId()).
when().
        get("/another_protected_resource").
then().
        statusCode(200);
```